# Retina 4inch simulator is misplacing everything in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, retina-display

After upgrading to xcode 5 then when I test my app on retina 4 inch screen, it misplaces some of the objects I've put in my app. I tried everything and only have one solution that may work but would be very annoying to do. It is the screen detection method. I really don't want to go through the hassle changing a lot of my code just so that it can be compatible with a 4inch retina, because I would have to rewrite a lot of code just for a 4inch retina display... Is there a way to make it so that everything could be stretched to fit to screen?

Comment: Can U put some snapshots .. ? and Using any - UInavigationcontroller Or UItabbarcontroller?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible Solutions:

1. For all of your nib (.xib) files or Views if using Storyboard, select View and set Size parameter value as "Retina 3.5-inch Full Screen". But using this one will fix your app screen height to 3.5inch.
2. In Inspector-tab, for every view items like labels, buttons, etc, set "Autosizing" parameters to stretch, reposition, fix or flexible positions and sizes of items according to change in screen height.

Comment: I don't the "view" option

Comment: Select the "View" for which the delegate is set towards the View Controller.

Comment: I see the "view" but there is no option to view as retina 3.5 inch full screen

Comment: no, it's not auto-layout.. select the view of any of your view controller (in simple terms, select a screen), from right column of Xcode, select "size inspector tab" (5th one), there you'll find "autosizing" box. try google or find tutorial how to use "autosizing". It's easy.. You can try it youserl too.. try changing values and see what happens..

Comment: select the view, from right column of Xcode, select "Attributes inspector tab", you'll find "size" parameter

Comment: Wait a minute... I'm an idiot it works! thank you!